# Trying to change the selected attribute dynamically after updated page

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I have had real struggle with this problem so hope some of you could help me out.
The site I have, got options where you can chose different backgroundcolors of the site, and then the colors that you have chosed are stored in localstorage. So after you update the page, the color is saved. However, the problem im having is that the drop down menu where you chose colors from, is not the same as the color that you last changed to.

Here's what i mean.
This is my HTML code

```html
<select id="selectcolor">
      <option value="css/css.css" id="grey">Standard grått</option>
      <option value="css/red.css" id="red">Häftigt rödigt!</option>
      <option value="css/green.css" id="green"> Häftigt grön-svart! </option>
    </select>
```

So this is what it looks like when i change the color

[image: Color pickture]

After that, when i refresh the page, this is what happens. The color remains RED but the options changes back to the standard one, not the red one.

[image: Color pickture]

Ive tried to change it dynamically with my javascript code that looks like this

```
var selectcolor = document.getElementById("selectcolor");
selectcolor.options[selectcolor.options.selectedIndex].selected = true;
```

But this doesnt seem to work, and i cant understand why..?
Would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: do you have a document onload function ? and your code inside it?

Comment: From what I can make out, your code is saying: whichever option of the dropdown is selected, set its selected status to true, which of course is already the case. You need to (instead of getting the selected index), get the index of the option which matches the current page colour, and set the selected property of -that- to true. Make sure this is executed on document ready.

Comment: @animake No i dont have an onload function.

Comment: try implementing that and so if you can provide the code you're using to make the localeStorage variable

Comment: It would be better to provide a jsfiddle to inspect your problem

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you're using `selectcolor.options.selectedIndex` inside a `selectcolor.option` .. where is your `localeStorage` variable here? when i changed `selectcolor.options.selectedIndex` with a static value of `2` it worked. I assume your `localeStorage` variable is the issue.

Try storing the selected index in your `localeStorage` variable and then do this:

```
var selectcolor = document.getElementById("selectcolor");
selectcolor.options[yourLocaleStorageVariable].selected = true;
```

**UPDATE**

```
<script>
   function changeBg() {
      var selectcolor = document.getElementById("selectcolor");
      document.body.style.background = selectcolor.options[selectcolor.selectedIndex].value;
      localStorage.setItem("selectedcolor", selectcolor.selectedIndex);
   }
</script>

<select id="selectcolor" onchange="changeBg()">
  <option value="" id="grey">Standard grått</option>
  <option value="red" id="red">Häftigt rödigt!</option>
  <option value="green" id="green"> Häftigt grön-svart! </option>
</select>

<script>
  var selectcolor = document.getElementById("selectcolor");
  if (localStorage.getItem("selectedcolor")) {
    selectcolor.options[localStorage.getItem("selectedcolor")].selected = true;
    document.body.style.background = selectcolor.options[selectcolor.selectedIndex].value;
  }
<script>
```

Try to base your logic on this code above. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for replying.
The problem i have now is that i need the drop down menu to get select to it.

var getsavedcolor = localStorage.getItem('color')
var f = document.getElementById("grey").value;
if(f == getsavedcolor){
  //Code to make the dropdown menu be selected for the value
}else{
  //
}

Comment: I didn't quiet get what you mean, but try to take a look at the updated answer above @PhilipCarlsson

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.
What i needed to apply is the `selectedIndex` attribute. So if anyone gets this problem im posting the solution
So the correct code would be

```
var getsavedcolor = localStorage.getItem('color')
var a = document.getElementById("grey").value;
var b = document.getElementById("red").value;
var c = document.getElementById("green").value;
if(a == getsavedcolor){
  document.getElementById('selectcolor').selectedIndex=0;
}else if (b == getsavedcolor){
  document.getElementById('selectcolor').selectedIndex=1;
}else if (c == getsavedcolor){
  document.getElementById('selectcolor').selectedIndex=2;
}else{
  document.getElementById('selectcolor').selectedIndex=0;
}
```